# Retrieve Tensor (Numpy)Value After tf.Estimator Training

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I have trained a simple autoencoder using `tf.Estimator`. During training a particular tensor `W` is updated where `W` is a matrix. After training I would like to retrieve `W` and read its values using `numpy`.

This is a simple task if I was not using `tf.Estimator`, I would call `.eval()` and pass my session. However, `Estimator` is a high level API and the initialization and use of the session is all done under the hood.

I also tried using `Estimator.predict` and `EstimatorSpec` to return `W` but it does not seem to work. I get the following error:

> TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected.

Is it possible to directly retrieve the `numpy` value of a tensor after training with `tf.Estimator`. If so, how?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow!  Providing a could example of your code will make it much more likely for someone to be able to help you.  If possible provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `W` is stored as a variable in your model, you can use the `get_variable_value` method of the `Estimator` object. See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#get_variable_value).